# Frame size error during landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

Frame size error during landscape,

[image: Portrait mode]
[image: Landscape mode]

The green label has height based on it's content, it's also applies to orange label.

The problem arises when the screen going to landscape.
As you can see those label's height are not resizing, they still have old height, same when during portrait mode.

(Please ignore cell height)

Comment: Have you tried calling `sizeToFit` on the labels?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't sure about that.
If I have 100 cell then I need to call sizeToFit for every label in each cell.
I need to do it through - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews,
but I can't change it unless it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath:method.
And cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't called during orientation changes.